# Laravel basic auth not working in using jwt

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am using laravel 5.6. I tried to use JWT. That's why I made some modification followed by https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/ . Now jwt is working properly.I checked it by postman. But when I try to use laravel basic login with email and password it does not work. Thanks in advance

I also made change on

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

...

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

is because you are telling laravel to use jwt as driver and the laravel basic login use session as driver, if you want to have both you may need to put this

```
        'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
         ],
```

and especify the guard that you will use for the login

```
 if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
   //
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback **'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],**
Its already there. Can you please tell me in **which file** I specify the guard (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials) )

Comment: in AuthenticatesUsers.php there is a method call attemptLogin you can change it there

Comment: Thanks to give your valuable time, but still not working